# Hello world code for Mountain Lion OSX 10.8 showing notification like iChat

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion

Is there any example for showing a hello world notification on Mountain Lion OSX 10.8 (the new notification center).

Just to add visual clarity here is what I am talking about:
[image: Notification Center Notification]

Comment: What have you searched for? What documentation have you read? What have you tried? What was the result?

Comment: I think its nothing you should be **over reacting** on. I just need example to start off! I googled and found jumbled examples and code samples for NSNotificationCenter. Any hints?

Comment: Put yourself in the position of the person answering your question. Someone's logical reaction to your apparent laziness is not rudeness. If you need it spelled out: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#before

Comment: Mine isn't the overreaction. Yours was not a "smart question" as Nicholas Riley's link would define it (a great read, by the way - definitely do so). Instead, it automatically put all the work off on us (even just to prod you for more info is unnecessary work you required of us). This is lazy and not appreciated in this community. If you don't like being asked for clarification, go elsewhere because it WILL happen.

Comment: It's not called rudeness all I can say is to try google Notification Center and see what you get (Nothing but NSNotificationCenter how the hell am I supposed to know that its called NSUserNotification?)! Just because **you** guys know the SDK already doesn't make **me** smart!

Comment: One more thing: If you write "the perfect question" that doesn't prompt requests for clarification, you probably already found the answer. When you get good at framing your question for others (heading off the "what did you search for? did you read the docs?"), you'll more often than not find the answer yourself before you even need to post. Describing the problem well and learning to use your reference material - Apple's docs in this case - will negate the need for most of your questions and you won't even need us.

Comment: Guys, I think this is an excellent question — if I didn't see Apple's WWDC videos (which kinda point to NSUserNotification), I'd _kill_ to have this example code that Max has posted below. I can see many people searching for this exact thing. Can we please reopen the question (and perhaps undo some of the downvotes)?

Comment: This is a great question. By the way: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/08/stack-exchange-is-not-a-forum-the-role-of-niceness-on-a-qa-site/

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I finally found answer after a little help from @Alexsander.

```objective-c
NSUserNotification *notification = [[NSUserNotification alloc] init];
[notification setTitle:@"Hello World"];
[notification setInformativeText:@"Hello world message"];
[notification setDeliveryDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:20 sinceDate:[NSDate date]]];
[notification setSoundName:NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName];
NSUserNotificationCenter *center = [NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter];
[center scheduleNotification:notification];
```

Hope it helps people

Comment: What should I include / configure in my .h in order to use the NSUserNotification type ?

Comment: You shouldn't have to include anything. Maybe you don't have the newest version of Xcode?

Answer (score 10):

Look up `NSUserNotification` and `NSUserNotificationCenter`.

Comment: This is a useless answer. There are not examples on or linked from those pages.

Comment: As of the time of writing the post, Mountain Lion was under NDA, so I wasn't exactly allowed to do much.